# How is possible for the accuracy to go down as the precision and recall go up?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm training a super simple Neural Network with TF and Keras to be the baseline of my real model. The data is all numerical so I just feed the network with it, nothing of preprocessing in this iteration because it is just to check everything is fine.

The problem comes when I check the training metrics and I find this:

[image]

The Precision and Recall are very acceptable but the Accuracy does not stop to go down and down...
My doubt is: How is this possible? In my naive intuition I supposed that if the Accuracy was bad, the Precision and Recall will be bad as well (I'm aware that the reverse effect is, in fact, an option that could happen, indicating that the data is probably imbalanced).
So am I doing something wrong? Or am I just interpreting the results wrong?

This is the code for the network construction:

```py
input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(12,))
dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=200, activation='relu')(input)
dense2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=200, activation='relu')(dense1)
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid')(dense2)

model = tf.keras.Model(input, output)
model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
    metrics=[
        tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy(), 
        tf.keras.metrics.Precision(), 
        tf.keras.metrics.Recall()
    ]
)

model.summary()
```

The worst is that when I check the Accuracy with the SKlearn method instead, the result makes sense (0.94), so I guess I'm not reading the results correctly and that Keras Accuracy must be indicating something else...

Any clarification on this, please?

Comment: Use `tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy`, not `tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy`. The former takes a threshold for deciding whether a prediction is a 0 or a 1, the latter checks _equality_. E.g. if `true=[0,1]` and `pred=[0, 0.9997]`, then the `Accuracy` would report 0.5 while `BinaryAccuracy` would report 1.

Comment: how is it possible as per my knowledge and experience both are inversely proportionally to each other as recall goes up precision goes down and vice versa... Have I missed something while learning?

Comment: @Brian thanks! That was definitely the problem. I usually specify the metric with just the string 'accuracy' (which seems to select automatically the right accuracy type) so that's why I did not have any idea about the difference between Accuracy and BinaryAccuracy. Thanks again!

Comment: @Ameya that's a good point. They are not mathematically inversely proportional (because, for example, in a perfect classifier they both would end up being 1), but there is definitely some trade-off that usually reduce one when the other increase so let's hope someone with more knowledge could bring us some light about this

Comment: should I open a question about it? hopefully, there'll be someone with a big brain to answer. what'd you think? @rmoret

Comment: Yes, definitely, go on! But maybe it's better if you post it on here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/ that's the Stack community for ML/Statistics, and due to this question is more theoretical than code related probably would be answered earlier (post the link here if you do it! I would love to keep track of it)